# Compiling and linking C and C++ files

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I would like to invoke a C++ function from within a C file and I have read about the extern "C" construct and the wrapper API. However, I am unsure how to organize the various header files and how to link the object files.

Assume I have a C file *MyProg.c* and its corresponding header file *MyProg.h*.

Now, I created two files *Wrapper.cpp* and *Wrapper.h* that declare the function I wish to call from MyProg.c

```
// Wrapper.h
#include "Utility.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void func_to_invoke();

#ifdef __cplusplus
     }
#endif
```

Note that Wrapper.h includes a file that contains other utility C++ functions.

The question is how to compile and link the files. Should I do the following:

```
g++ -c Utility.cpp Utility.h
g++ -c Wrapper.cpp Wrapper.h Utility.h
gcc -c MyProg.c MyProg.h Wrapper.h

gcc MyProg.o Wrapper.o
```

EDIT:

I have tried the following and I still can't compile. I have pages and pages of errors related to the C++ libraries. Should I also declare all the functions in Utility.h within a __cplusplus macro?

```
g++ -c Utility.cpp
g++ -c Wrapper.cpp 
gcc -c MyProg.c 
g++ MyProg.o Wrapper.o Utility.
```

SOLUTION:

Utility.h must be removed from Wrapper.h and included in Wrapper.cpp

Comment: I think the last call should be `gcc MyProg.o Wrapper.o Utility.o`

Comment: You don't need to specify the ".h" files to the compiler, it will find them from the "#include" statements.

Comment: I just noticed that you include Utility.cpp in your wrapper.h file. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is a Q&A database, not a message board or forum or helpdesk or chat room; please do not edit in new questions after-the-fact. Post a new one (with a [testcase](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my edits are really progressions of the original problem that this post addresses. It is certainly useful for people who might encounter the same initial problem. Anyway, thanks for the information. I shall make a new post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Do not** include a .cpp file in your Wrapper header. That is entirely the wrong thing to do. Do not even include the Utility.h header. Just define your wrapper function. Then in Wrapper.cpp include the Utility.h header and define the wrapper function.

If your C++ code uses exceptions or runtime type information you will need to do the final link with g++. Your program will need the C++ support library.

I would write it like this:

```
g++ -c Utility.cpp
g++ -c Wrapper.cpp
gcc -c MyProg.c
g++ -o MyProg Utility.o MyProg.o Wrapper.o
```

Comment: I have tried exactly this and I still can't compile. I have pages and pages of errors related to the C++ libraries. Should I also declare all the functions in Utility.h within a __cplusplus macro?

Comment: @NewToAndroid: Utility.h only needs cplus macros if it gets included into a C program. If Wrapper.h includes Utility.h and MyProg includes Wrapper.h, then yes. However, I recommend that Wrapper.h not include any C++ headers.

Comment: @NewToAndroid: Wrapper.cpp can include Utility.h. Wrapper.h should not include it.

Comment: @ZanLynx Thank you so much, you did solve many of the compilation problems but there's one last problem related to "multiple definition of". I have a global variable declared as "TYPE X" in Utility.h. The func_to_invoke() in Wrapper.cpp also needs this variable. Therefore, I have declared it in Wrapper.cpp as "extern TYPE X". When I link Wrapper.o and Utility.o, I get the error message: multiple definition of X in Utility.o, X was first defined in Wrapper.o

Comment: Please don't write new questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've compiled `Wrapper.cpp` into object code, it really doesn't matter whether its contents were previously written in C or C++, as long as you use `extern "C"` to tell the compiler to skip name mangling for `func_to_invoke`.

If I remember well, both `gcc` and `g++` can detect whether their input files contain C or C++ code and do the right thing, but `gcc` will link against the C standard library and `g++` against C++'s, so it's possible that you end up with some missing functionality.

I think the best course of action would be to use `gcc` for anything that *doesn't use any C++ feature*, as it would be the case with C, and `g++` for everything else.

Comment: Yes but you can end up without library support

Comment: Oh yeah, isn't the case that `gcc` links against the C standard library, whereas `g++` does it with C++'s?

Comment: Exactly. It'll build _your_ file properly according to its file extension, but the rest is still not quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you should include Utility.o in the last line.