# Recall a struct from C++ to C

Tags: c++, c, function, struct

I'm trying to read a struct of a program i wrote in `c++` into a `c` program. I created a `.h` with the `struct` and the `extern C` for the function. Then i wrote the C++ program that read a `csv file` and save some elements in a `struct`. Now i have to recall the `struct` in a C program and read the values but i'm having a lot of problems. I don't know if i make some mistake in the `.cpp file` , in the `.h file` or in the C program. I'm working under linux.

My `.h file` is :

```
typedef struct Buses{
 int maggiore;
 int minore;
}BusesStruct;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void get_buses(BusesStruct *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "lettura.h"
using namespace std;

void get_buses(BusesStruct * bus_scelti){
//leggo il file csv
    string line,nomefile;
    ifstream myfile;
    cout << "Quale file si vuole aprire? " << endl;
    cin >> nomefile;
    myfile.open(nomefile.c_str());
    int j=0;
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        int primobus;
        int secondobus;
        cout << "Digitare il numero di uno dei due BUS sul quale si vuole eseguire l'operazione (1-9): " << endl;
        cin >> primobus;
        cout << "Digitare il numero di un secondo BUS sul quale si vuole eseguire l'operazione (1-9): " << endl;
        cin >> secondobus;
        int bus1_scelto;
        int bus2_scelto;
        while (getline(myfile,line)) {
            istringstream myline(line);
            string bus[10];
            for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
                    getline(myline,bus[i+1],';');
                }

            for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
                if(i == primobus){
                    int bus1_scelto_c = atoi(bus[i].c_str());
                    bus1_scelto=bus1_scelto_c;
                }
                if(i == secondobus){
                    int bus2_scelto_c = atoi(bus[i].c_str());
                    bus2_scelto=bus2_scelto_c;
                }
            }
            bus_scelti[j].maggiore=max(bus1_scelto,bus2_scelto);
            bus_scelti[j].minore=min(bus1_scelto,bus2_scelto);
            j=j+1;          
        }   
    }
}
```

In my C file i wrote `#include lettura.h` to recall the function :

```
BusesStruct bus_scelti[10005];
get_buses(bus_scelti);
```

And to define my vector and recall the function.
I got the `error` :

> reference not define to 'get_buses'.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `extern "C" {` ? The `get_buses()` function is C++. [What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1041866)

Comment: `extern "C" void get_buses(BusesStruct * bus_scelti){` should be in definition too.

Comment: Are you linking in the cpp?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the `extern "C"` is so the function can be called from C code, which OP is trying to do. It doesn't matter that the function definition is in C++.

Comment: i use the extern "C" to read the values of the struct in the C file. In the c++ file i read the csv and save the elements in the struct.

Comment: extern "C" just makes the function name compatible.  It doesn't have any effect on the data being passed as arguments.

Comment: Ok. I see. I missed that part. Are you getting the error from the linker?

Comment: i'm getting the error when i try to complie the C file where i define the vector and recall the function

Comment: How are you compiling it exactly ?

Comment: g++ -c lettura.cpp for the cpp file. For the c file i use g++ complete.c -o complete .

Comment: So you aren't linking the C++ file into the executable? That's the problem.

Comment: Can you wrote me the command i have to use? I'm new on C and linux

Comment: the content of question is quite poor as it appears, because it is a build process problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling and linking C and C++ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154119/compiling-and-linking-c-and-c-files)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment this is how you're compiling:

> `g++ -c lettura.cpp` for the cpp file. For the c file i use `g++ complete.c -o complete`

This is compiling the C++ file into an object file and then compiling the C file into an executable. You need to link in the object file as well.

A few options:

```
g++ -c lettura.cpp                   # compile C++ file to lettura.o
gcc -c complete.c                    # compile C file to complete.o
g++ lettura.o complete.o -o complete # link object files into executable 'complete'

g++ lettura.cpp complete.c -o complete # compile and link in one step
```

Note that I'm using `gcc` to compile the C code and `g++` to compile the C++ code and to link.

Ideally you should use a Makefile for this, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: Better use `-Wall -Wextra -g`  for both `gcc` and `g++`

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try

Comment: Ok, now they compiles without errors but when i launch ./COMPLETE it stops after a while. Maybe i made an error when i recall the values. I'll search for the errors. Thanks

Comment: The code now compiles and work correctly. Thanks